# How to fix 'ERROR:Xst - basic_stringFATAL_ERROR' error in Xilinx fpga?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, synthesis

I have been trying to synthesize a vhdl code which simulates perfectly in Active HDL but I get the following error when synthesizing.

ERROR:Xst - basic_stringFATAL_ERROR:Xst:Portability/export/Port_Main.h:159:1.18 - This application has discovered an exceptional condition from which it cannot recover.  For technical support on this issue, please visit http://www.xilinx.com/support.

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD_UNSIGNED.all;

library work;
use work.common.all;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity main is
     port(
         CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
         reset : in STD_LOGIC;
         V_Out : out STD_LOGIC
         );
end main;

--}} End of automatically maintained section

architecture main of main is

signal text : string (1 to 15) := "This is a Test.";
signal text_len : integer := 15;
signal x : integer := 50;
signal y : integer := 50;

type vramt is array (0 to H_480_272p_AV*V_480_272p_AV-1) of std_logic_vector (0 downto 0);
signal vram : vramt := (others => (others => '0'));

--signal vram : std_logic_vector(H_480_272p_AV*V_480_272p_AV-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
attribute RAM_STYLE : string;
attribute RAM_STYLE of vram: signal is "BLOCK";
signal vram_we : std_logic;
signal vram_addr, vram_wraddr : INTEGER range 0 to H_480_272p_AV*V_480_272p_AV-1;
signal rom_addr : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0);
signal rom_data : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin

    inst_get_char : entity work.Font_Rom PORT MAP (
        clk => CLK,
        addr => rom_addr,
        data => rom_data    
    );

    Process (CLK)

    begin
        if rising_edge (CLK) then
        if vram_addr = H_480_272p_AV*V_480_272p_AV-1 then
            vram_addr <= 0;
        end if; 
        vram_addr <= vram_addr + 1;
        V_Out <= vram(vram_addr)(0);
        end if;
    end process;



    Process (CLK)
    variable char_count : integer := 1;
    variable pix_line : integer := 0;
    variable bit_count : integer := 0;
    variable curr_char : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    variable bit_data : std_logic;
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            if bit_count = 0 then 
                rom_addr <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(character'pos(text(char_count)), 7)) & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(pix_line, 4));
            end if;
            bit_data := rom_data(bit_count);
            vram_wraddr <= (y + pix_line)*H_480_272p_AV + (x + bit_count + (8* (char_count-1)));
            vram(vram_wraddr)(0) <= bit_data;

            if bit_count = 7 then
                bit_count := 0;
                if pix_line = 15 then
                    pix_line := 0;
                    if char_count = text_len then
                        char_count := 1;
                    else
                        char_count := char_count + 1;
                    end if;
                else
                    pix_line := pix_line + 1;
                end if;

            else
                bit_count := bit_count + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end Process;

end main;
```

Comment: This is a bug in Vivado/ISE. Even if there is a syntax error in your code, the compiler should report an error message, it should not crash. This is not the forum for sorting out bugs in EDA tools. As your error message suggests, you need to contact Xilinx support. Just as is the case with asking a question here, you should compile an [MCVE] before contacting Xilinx. In doing so, you may well find out what line of your code is causing the crash and may well find a (temporary) workaround.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.